# Can demons give visions as Gods to humans?

Tags: gods, asuras, pramana, darshan, demon

Can demons appear as Gods to humans, in order to spread Adharma among humans?
And if this is possible, how should one distinguish between a vision from a demon and a vision from a god?

Comment: Yeah Kali asur is infact invisible, he gets in to the body of humans and make them evil?

Comment: Also to stay away from such visions, One should chant the name of the Lord and ask him for the protection from the Maya

Answer (score 2):

Can demons send visions to humans, and in these visions pretend to be gods, in order to spread lies among humans?

Yes, they can appear as Divine beings and cause nuisance just because by being at strikingly identical as divine, the human would worship them, and in turn these spirits would get ahara (food).

I would narrate a very true incident of Vrindavana which would serve as a complete answer to your query.
This was narrated by Shree Rajendradasji Maharaj in one of his sermons.

> The tale starts from Vrindavana. A Vaishnava was too impatient person and wanted to realize Krishna in person very quickly. He had a guru, who directed him on mantra and sadhana path. To his surprise all his gurubhratas (disciples under same guru) were having Krishna darshan or some sort of leela experience. He was alone left out of crowd even though so many years had passed him doing his sadhana. The sishya thought his Guru isn't perfect for him, or he purposely gave him a faulty mantra. And thus sobbing one night he ventered out of his house. He started moving along Yamuna banks for days. On one evening while was still weeping for his helpless state, a sadhu approached him and asked the reason. The sishya opened everything up to that sadhu. Soon hearing the narration the sadhu laughed and said, "oh boy, you want to see Krishna as simple as that, come today with some eatables at night to my hut, I promise I won't disappoint you." As said, the sishya gathered a lot of eatables and went to that Saddhu's hut.
>
> Soon, the sadhu started chanting mantras and said, "Oh, Krishna run to your child. Your Bhaktas today call you with sweets and offering. Oh, the grazer of cow the Gopala thy come." And soon saying so a black spirit arosed in the flickering light of lamps in hut. The Vaishnava was excited he saw, his Krishna with flute in hands and Vanamala in his neck with curly hairs and red lips. Adorned with peacock headgear. And with a cow behind him. The devotee cried and hugged his lord. Soon, Bhagwan ate the Bhoga and left. The sadhu said, "your Prabhu loves bhoga, so come everyday with bhoga for both him and his Cow."
>
> The bhakta used to now spend surplus to feed his swamy the best he could. Every night the same scenario used to happen. The bhakta was convinced that his guruji had cheated with him in mantra diksha. So, he staryed serving this sadhu very heartily.
>
> Soon, the true guru of the sishya got to know of all this from his other sishyas. He thought it is not possible for him to see Krishna so early. Thus, he decided to see what's going on in the hut of that sadhu, in person. It was night again, all fallen to deep sleep. The sadhu started to chant mantra. But, today the Shyamavarna Krishna didn't came. The sadhu tried again, this time with more intensity, but no results. Alas, the lord as upset it seemed. The sadhu asked the Bhakta, "did you buy surplus good sweets?" The Bhakta noded and opened the box before him. The sadhu, was confused. He took a lot of samagri like, perfumery, flowers, incense etc and again tried but no results. Hopelessly he said, "Oh Krishna, please tell us what makes you displeased today with your devotees, why you make us wait so longer?".
> A roar appeared from sky like thunderbolt. It said,"I can't come here, there is a old man behind the door watching, I can't come till he's here." As the voice said so, the original guru came from his hideout and caught hold his shishya's hand and pulled him out from there and went to his Ashram. The shishya too had no guts to cross question his guru as why he was dragging him away from the sadhu.
> The sishya was confused. In morning when guruji was alone he called the sishya, he said, "So you had visions of Krishna everyday I heard?" The sishya noded. Guruji laughed like hysteric man. The sishya got a bit anger and dared to ask, "What is so funny Guruji, I saw Krishna with my own eyes." Guruji said, "Son, the Krishna you used to see was the Spirit of a cow grazer called Krishna, and the cow you used to see was his cow. Once, when Yamuna was flooded the cow was drowning in it, to save her the guy named Krishna too jumped in it. But, alas by fate they both died. No antim sanskaras where done as bodies couldn't be found. So, your Krishna was an atript Atma. The sadhu you served as a person who lures such impatient sadhakas and make living by such people. And the reason you couldn't have experience with Krishna when previously you were doing sadhana, mantra and bhajan, was because you had some Prarabdha left. Once, it was to be completed, you would have been definitely be blessed by Krishna."
>
> The sishya got dumbfolded and stayed silent. He decided to renounce world and serve his guru who was such an illuminated soul.

And if this is possible, how can we distinguish between a vision from a demon and a vision from a god?

We in ourselves are not that capable ever to realize that whether, is it really our Ishta or any lesser entity. For example, mostly all Devi sadhanas have this hurdle where any lesser being tries to imitates Devi's form and lure you to serve her. (Sometimes devtas too try to scare or lure, that's only to test a sadhaka).
But, remember, only a true Guru can understand and guide us accordingly, we in ourselves can't even know our own nature, and who we are! Leave alone of recognizing some Bhoot preta and our ishta.
Thus, one must completely resort to the feet of guru.

Comment: Very true.. Without a Guru to guide, self realisation is indeed very difficult.